# django : py manage.py runserver command doesnt work

Tags: django, python-3.x

I installed python 3.8.1 and django 3.0.3
Following tutorials I already created project but couldnt run server

```
PS D:\Study\django> django-admin startproject mysite
PS D:\Study\django> py --version
Python 3.8.1
PS D:\Study\django> py -m django --version
3.0.3
PS D:\Study\django> cd .\mysite\
PS D:\Study\django\mysite> py .\manage.py runserver
PS D:\Study\django\mysite> py .\manage.py runserver
PS D:\Study\django\mysite>
```

My working directory is

[image]

and terminal is

[image]

I read similar questions here, nothing doesnt help.
What's the issue?

Comment: I'd recommend you not to use django in Windows, or if you do, containerize it with docker. It's much simpler to use it in a Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
PS D:\Study\django\mysite> .\manage.py runserver
```

**Or**

```
PS D:\Study\django\mysite> python manage.py runserver
```

If still nothing seems to work, maybe `python` or `django` installation was not successful. In this case, try installing `django` first, if still not works, try installing `python`. Hope it will do.

Comment: Both are not working. In python 2.7, I could run tutorial codes. But after installed Python 3.8.1, it didnt work

Comment: It doesnt any error messages or outputs
like this
```
PS D:\Study\django\mysite> .\manage.py runserver   

PS D:\Study\django\mysite> py manage.py runserver  

PS D:\Study\django\mysite> py .\manage.py runserver

PS D:\Study\django\mysite> .\manage.py runserver

```
http://prntscr.com/r0lfen
I dont know how to show image  or code in comment
Sorry

Comment: @WenchengLi, Add image of your working directory and errors in the question by editing it

Comment: Are you using any virtual-environment? Are you sure about your python path??

Comment: I added python paths manually, so I am sure of it. let's me try new command. Just checked it. It also not working

Comment: I think your `Django` and `Python` or both installation has some issues. I think you can try by reinstalling `Django` first and if it's not working still, try reinstalling `Python`. Good luck